# Sync PRESTASHOP with my own php application

Tags: php, synchronization, prestashop

I'm developing an application (php based) and I need to sync PRESTASHOP (1.6).
I see there are api library for interface with prestashop, but I can't find a way to get the status of orders.

what i need: 
1. when new order is delivered (through a cronjob) update the product quantity in my application.
2. when in my application new order is delivered (through a cronjob) update the product quantity in prestashop.

i know i need to map all product with my application.

Comment: WHat have you so far? (Show some code)

Comment: I have no real code at the moment, cause I tried with official prestashop example. Here the docs-> http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service
and here the code if you need -> https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/archive/master.zip

Comment: Then it's probably time to do the first steps with product sync. Orders can also be read from the shop.

Comment: yes but, how I can browsing all the orders? with the API i can't see order status... or i'm wrong?
(and I can't connect directly to prestashop database)

Comment: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Web+service+reference look for the orders REST collection and then the details

Comment: I'll tried something like this: http://localhost/prestashop/api/orders/
and this showing me all orders but, if I try to browse one single order  (http://localhost/prestashop/api/orders/1) i get an error: <![CDATA[
Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.
]]>

Comment: good! in "order_details" there are ID_PRODUCT and QUANTITY. How I know if the order is delivered or canceled?

Comment: order_states ? Do you handle the delivery/cancel states via the shopsoftware?

Comment: no :(
In order_states there are the list of all state available for the orders

Comment: any tips for get the status of the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
http://localhost/prestashop/api/orders/1
http://localhost/prestashop/api/orders/2
```

if this doesn't works, try to update to 1.6.X.

With version 1.5.X doesn't works and I don't know why...